# Unable to tag on Custom Models

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I've created a custom Model & associated the same to a Node Template. Changed the template document type to this model. The custom model has couple of properties & couple of Aspects attached to it. I'm trying to add a Tag to a document created fromt his template & when I click on the Edit icon in Tags section, I see only the Document Custom Properties entry window. I've added the *Taggable* Aspect to this document also, but despite that I'm unable to see the Tags.

Aren't documents created with Custom Models taggable ?
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added taggable Aspect to the template. But it should be added in the Model itself & be added using the Layout Designer.